# AJAX запрос с помощью fetch и javascript по реально не существующему URL

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

В процессе изучения javascript столкнулся с необходимостью получить JSON по url вида:
http://mysite.ru/data/**width**/**height**
Здесь width и height представляют собой не названия папок на сервере, а значения ширины и высоты изображения в пикселах в результатах запроса.

Насколько я знаю, обычный Get-запрос с параметрами мог бы иметь, например, такой вид:
[http://mysite.ru/data/?width="150"&height="200"](http://mysite.ru/data/?width=%22150%22&height=%22200%22)

А каким образом я мог бы обработать внутри fetch() ссылку вот такого вида:
http://mysite.ru/data/150/200, чтобы первый параметр был шириной, а второй - высотой изображения в пикселах?

Comment: Заберите всю строку запроса и разбейте по шаблону на куски. Каждый отдельно обрабатывайте, как пожелаете.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, что значит "обработать" и при чём тут fetch?

Comment: Серверная часть может получать данные нескольких "типов"... Для `Node.js` это `query`, `body` и `params`. Вот тебе как раз интересует `params`. https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.15.php

Comment: С помощью fetch() я должен сделать запрос к серверу по url. Извините, я неточно выразился: я имел ввиду не "обработать", а "сконструировать ссылку такого вида, чтобы затем использовать её, как аргумент fetch()"

Comment: Спасибо, ksa! Я попробую применить предложенный Вами способ.

Comment: @UspenskiyKE `\`http://mysite.ru/data/${width}/${height}\`` - вы это имеете ввиду?